# Fundamental Problems in Mathematics that, without Computer Sciences, would not be resolved?

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, mathematical-philosophy

Could you please give examples of fundamental questions in mathematics (let us say, pure mathematics) which were resolved *fundamentally* by the use of computers? More precisely, are there examples that you can compare to the accomplishments that Gauss, Ramanujan, Riemann, Grothendieck, Deligne, Wiles, Perelman, etc. obtained? Let me make precise that my question does not mean that I do not advocate the use computers as a powerful tool.

Comment: What is "fundamental"? How about the four color conjecture? I think it was the first one "accepted" by the community.

Comment: Please do not write words in all capitals to emphasize them. And names only have the first letter capitalized, not all of them.

Comment: I know about the four color conjecture.But as far as I know, GAUSS, RAMANUJAN,..., could not check the proof. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Using computers and using computer science are two different things, at least to me...

Comment: @ Yuichiro Fujiwara : To me too .

Answer (score 4):

Existence of Lorentz attractor was proved in part using rigorous numerics impemented on a computer.
http://www2.math.uu.se/~warwick/main/papers/comptes.pdf